# Phonegap 3.0 command line no such file or directory error

Tags: cordova, command

While trying to add a plugin or do a build I get the error below. the config.xml does exist at that location

The commands I am using are

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

and

```
$ phonegap build ios
```

The error

```
fs.js:427
 return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
             ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/Tiltmac1/Sites/RBG/plantbank-   app/platforms/ios/PlantBank/config.xml'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/xml-helpers.js:107:27)
at Object.config_parser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/config_parser.js:25:20)
at Object.ios_parser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/ios_parser.js:61:19)
at doInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/plugin.js:131:50)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/src/plugin.js:152:41
at runInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:192:23)
at possiblyFetch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:62:9)
at Object.installPlugin (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:42:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi "git" is also a node module. you should install plugin like this.

npm install -g git

This will install git in you node source location as a module.

Restart the machine.

Install phonegap plugin: C:\Users\user1\yourprojectname>cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git

You will get response as: Fetching plugin from "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-cam era.git"... Starting installation of "org.apache.cordova.camera" for android Preparing android project org.apache.cordova.camera installed on android.

Answer (score -2):

Could it be all the spaces? "RBG/plantbank-   app/platforms"